# Can't deploy app on GitHub using gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages

I have deployed a few days ago React app on GitHub. Yesterday I made changes and something went wrong - I deleted gh-pages after pushing changes on master branch and when I type in terminal

```
npm run deploy
```

I have error like this
[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. How to update website in github.io when I made changes?
2. How can I deploy app again on GitHub pages?

Edit:
Here's solution:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4854

Answer (score 0):

If you want that GitHub use your master branch to display your website, you have to rename your repository to xxx.github.io. Or you can push your content to gh-pages branch so GitHub will generate the content under yourname.github.io/repo_name .

Make sure your content is OK. The problem you met seems related to your npm tool.

Comment: It is not necessary to display the page from the master branch.

I created gh-pages branch and webiste is working, but it shows README page. Do You know how to change that?

Comment: You visited the xxx.github.io page ？ make sure your site can be generate by GitHub Page.

Comment: From what I know the link to the repository should look like this: https://<my.user>.github.io/<repo.name>

Answer (score 0):

I have my react app running on gh-pages. Here are the changes I made in package.json to get it there:

STEP 1 - Install gh-pages in dev-dependencies:

```
npm i gh-pages --save-dev
```

STEP 2 - Add deploy script:

```
"deploy" : "npm run build&&gh-pages -d build",
```

STEP 3 - Add `homepage` key at top of package.json with `name` key etc.:

```
"homepage": "https://<username>.github.io/<git-repo-name>/",
```

STEP 4 - Run command to deploy:

```
npm run deploy
```

This should host the app on gh-pages on URL you specified in key homepage. Every time you make changes, just run the command specified in STEP 4 locally to publish changes.

Comment: I did as you wrote and I have error in pic. This step 4 you are doing from which branch?

Comment: master. I doubt you have correct homepage url. Its hould be https://<username>.github.io/<git-repo-name>/

Comment: Homepage in package.json is same as you wrote. In browser this URL shows a README file.

One thing - after npm run deploy i have error the same as in the pic.